# Is there a way to kill a loop pass that lasts over 1 min and go to the next loop pass in batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, taskkill

The jhove script will process all files %%a from my %input% directory in a for loop. As far as I know taskkill is only used for killing the .exe files but not one loop pass. Would it be possible for this code to wait 60 seconds then kill the loop pass and go to the next one? So do smth. like that  `timeout /t 1/nobreak>nul   taskkill /F /IM "%%a"`

```
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s %input%\*.*') do ( 
         echo Verarbeite %%~na
         CALL jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o "%output%\%%~na_!count!.xml" "%%a"
         set /a count=count+1
         set /a loop3+=1
     )
```

Comment: Batch has no such functionality. Although you could `start` your `jhove` with a unique title and after a `timeout` you can `taskkill` that spawned process.

Comment: Are you saying you want to kill the `jhove` process if it is still running after 60 seconds?

Comment: I want to kill one jhove process in the loop if it hangs more than one minute and continue the jhove loop with the next file

Answer (score 0):

You can of course do something like this:

```cmd
> nul timeout /T 60 /NOBREAK
taskkill ...
```

But this will wait for 60 seconds even if the process quits before that time elapses.

I would use a polling loop instead and query via `tasklist` whether or not the process is still running, and if not, go on with processing the next item. Here is a possible way how to accomplish that (see the comments):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_INPUT=."               & rem // (path to input directory)
set "_OUTPUT=."              & rem // (path to output directory)
set "_MASK=*.*"              & rem // (input file name pattern)
set "_SCRIPT=%~dp0jhove.bat" & rem // (script to process input files by)
set "_TITLE=JHOVE"           & rem // (base window title of script process)
set "_FROZEN="               & rem // (only terminate frozen processes if not empty)
set /A "_TIMEOUT=60"         & rem // (timeout value for process; zero means none)

set /A "COUNT=0"
rem // Resolve output directory:
for %%D in ("%_OUTPUT%") do (
    rem // Iterate through all input files:
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "%_INPUT%\%_MASK%"') do (
        rem // Process input files in a sub-routine:
        call :RUN -m PDF-hul -h xml -o "%%~fD\%%~nF_%%COUNT%%.xml" "%%~F"
        set /A "COUNT+=1"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:RUN
    rem // Build unique window title:
    set "WTITLE=%_TITLE%_%RANDOM%"
    rem // Build image name from command prompt specification:
    for %%I in ("%ComSpec%") do set "IMAGE=%%~nxI"
    rem // Run script using unique window title:
    start "%WTITLE%" /D "%_INPUT%" "%ComSpec%" /D /S /C ^""%_SCRIPT%" %*^"
    rem // Skip polling loop in case timeout is set to zero, thus deactivated:
    if %_TIMEOUT% leq 0 goto :END
    rem // Set filter according to given configuration:
    if defined _FROZEN (set "FILTER=/FI "STATUS ne RUNNING"") else set "FILTER="
    rem // Try termination without forcing first:
    set "FORCE="
    rem // Reset timer:
    set /A "TIMER=0"
    rem // Reset error flag:
    set "ERR=0"
    :LOOP
    rem // Retrieve PID of running command prompt process with unique window title:
    set "PID=0"
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%T in ('
        2^> nul tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %IMAGE%" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %WTITLE%" ^
            /FO LIST /V
    ') do (
        if "%%T"=="PID" for /F %%V in ("%%U") do set "PID=%%V"
        if "%%T"=="Status" for /F "tokens=*" %%V in ("%%U") do set "STATUS=%%V"
    )
    rem // Skip loop if no PID has been found (process might already be finished):
    if %PID% equ 0 goto :END
    rem // Wait for a second, so this is the polling rate:
    > nul timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK
    rem // Increment timer:
    set /A "TIMER+=1"
    rem // Check whether timeout limit is reached, loop if not:
    if %TIMER% leq %_TIMEOUT% goto :LOOP
    rem /* Loop if process is frozen, if desired (this filter (`/FI`) cannot applied
    rem    to `taskkill` below, because mismatch would not set the exit code, hence
    rem    use of conditional operators `&&` and `||` would not work): */
    if defined FILTER for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%T in ('
        2^> nul tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %IMAGE%" /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %WTITLE%" ^
            %FILTER% /FO LIST /V
    ') do if "%%T"=="INFO" goto :LOOP
    rem /* Try to terminate process with found PID (`taskkill` sets the exit code in
    rem    case filters `/PID` or `/IM` deliver a mismatch, but not for `/FI`): */
    > nul 2> nul taskkill /PID %PID% %FORCE% && (
        rem // Termination succeeded, so return information message:
        echo Successfully terminated process:
        call :MSG %*
        rem // Set error flag:
        set "ERR=1"
    ) || (
        rem // Termination failed:
        if not defined FORCE (
            rem // Normal termination failed, so try termination forcefully now:
            set "FORCE=/F"
            goto :LOOP
        ) else (
            rem // Forceful termination failed, so return error message:
            >&2 (
                echo Failed to terminate process:
                call :MSG %*
            )
            rem // Set error flag:
            set "ERR=2"
        )
    )
    :END
    rem /* Exit with exit code (`ErrorLevel`) set to `0` if no process had to be
    rem    terminated, `1` if at least one process had to be terminated, and `2`
    rem    if at least one process could not be terminated (forcefully): */
    exit /B %ERR%


:MSG
    rem // Return some process details:
    echo   PID         = %PID%
    echo   image name  = %IMAGE%
    echo   status      = %STATUS%
    echo   window title= %WTITLE%
    echo   command line= "%_SCRIPT%" %*
    echo/
    exit /B
```